# XPath for the element with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, selenium, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to find a button and click on it. I am using selenium with c# and also have protractor. I am not able to find the element.

```
<button class="btn--primary quote-summary__card-btn" role="button" aria-label="Choose Essential Cover" ng-disabled="!quoteSecondaryOptionsCtl.pageLoaded" ng-click="quoteSecondaryOptionsCtl.selectCover('Essential', 0)" style="">Choose</button>
```

could anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Show how you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try following `XPATH`.

```
//button[@class='btn--primary quote-summary__card-btn' and text()='Choose']
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how your page is structured. Do you have any unique identifiers other than the button text? If not, then locate it with XPath:

`//button[contains(text(), 'Choose')]`

If you want to locate it by your ng-click param then you can use css selector:

`button[ng-click="quoteSecondaryOptionsCtl.selectCover('Essential', 0)"]`